# Unable to login palo alto firewall post rebooting the device!

Tags: firewall, palo-alto

I would like to give brief background, Please go through the below details:-

- Palo Alto firewalls have bug for Software version 5.0.12 (Confirmed by PA TAC team)
- This bug will not hamper the user traffic but potentially may cause outage resulting in isolation
- As per PA, The firewalls those have uptime of more than 365 days will loose their configuration due to this bug
- Hence PA team have suggested firewall reboot as a work around and later to upgrade the firewall to latest version

Hence as per PA TAC teams recommendation, We have rebooted one of the firewall but have lost the management for the same. If someone have faced/facing this issue then would really appreciate response.

Thanks a lot and have a great day ahead.

Rgds // Rounak

Comment: Can you connect via Console port? Can you connect via Management out of band port?

Comment: If you can't connect via console, then get Palo Alto Support back on the phone.  You may need to RMA the failed device.  I'll also add to upgrade to at least 5.1 to avoid the bug.

Comment: @KorXo: Thanks a lot for writing. Unfortunately we didn't had the out of band support for this FW and Onsite support was unavailable so no Console connection. I got the management in 30-40 minutes automatically. Was just panicked as had lost management.

Comment: @Theo: Thanks mate. We did the same just as you have advised. PA TAC as usual had requested reboot but we got the management after 30-40 minutes automatically. So all well.

Please pass on the information as this is potential bug for the PA FW's and can cause service outages / disruptions going forward.
Thanks.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Hey Ron, I've added the answer, this post can now be closed. Thank you so much for your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PA TAC confirmed this as a bug with the software version and had intimated other customers post our feedback. Thank you all for assistance.